# Proper implementation/use of code/syntax highlighting

Tags: code, syntax-highlighting, plugin-syntaxhighlighter

I've already read what I can on a couple of sites and installed this plug-in:

http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

I'm missing how to make it work. Now I have two questions:

1. Do I have to type in the Visual window or the HTML
   window?
2. Does TinyMCE mess with this?  I've seen my code
   disappear in the HTML window.

I currently have typed in my code in Visual Window like this:

```
[sourcecode language="php"]
<?
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
Header( "Location: http://CMSTrainingVideos.com" );
if ($_GET["page_id"] == 1)
   Header( "Location: http://CMSTrainingVideos.com/?p=35");
if ($_GET["page_id"] == 2)
   Header( "Location: http://CMSTrainingVideos.com/?p=43");
?>
[/sourcecode]
```

I also tried `<pre language="php">` with the "Geshi" syntax highligher, and no luck there either.

But nothing is happening, i.e. no syntax highlighting: http://cmstrainingvideos.com/?p=53

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a similar plugin called WP Syntax, which works better, in my experience, so I'm going to answer for that one:

> Question 1: Do I have to type in the Visual window or the HTML window?

In the HTML window. I prefer the `<pre lang="php">` mode.

> Question 2: Does TinyMCE mess with this?

Yes, it will html encode special chars, for example transforming `=>` into `=&gt;` etc. so you should probably disable the rich editor alltogether.

Comment: Thanks, finally got it to sort of work.  It looks really ugly though - like the styles are not being picked up correctly. http://cmstrainingvideos.com/?p=53 Any suggestions now? Before, I was actually losing code when I put it in the HTML editor, but maybe when it is in the <pre> tag, it preserves it.

Comment: You have some conflicting CSS from the Twentyten theme. You can right-click -> Inspect element using Firefox + Firebug or Chrome to sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/visual-code-editor/ prevents the code wrangling:

first put the sourcecode tags, then mark it as pre, then copy your code in between, it will not HTML encode the stuff.

So you do not have disable your Visual Editor anymore.

Answer (score -2):

I have been installing and removing many plugins to highlight my code on my blog.Finally, I managed to use **Prettify GC Syntax Highlighter** effectively.

I also posted step by step configuration and usage guide for the plugin [here](http://www.technologyspirit.com/prettify-gc-syntax-highlighter-one-of-the-stable-syntax-highlighter-plugin/)

Be warned though, tinyMCE will mess codes with  **Prettify GC Syntax Highlighter** as well. If you plan to include codes in your posts, get used to the HTML editor, not the visual editor.